# Angularjs get translations from api directive

Tags: angularjs, drupal-7

I use drupal as backend and as texts manager.

So I want to insert string keys in html and then send request with all keys for getting real text in current lang.

So I want to make some stuff like

```
<h4 ng-gettext>MODULE_Y__STRING1</h4>
<span ng-gettext>MODULE_X__STRING1</span>
<span ng-gettext>MODULE_X__STRING3</span>
```

Then in NgGettext directive I want to send request with all strings like

```
var strings = [];
EACH.('ng-gettext', function(){
  strings.push($(this).html());
});
$.when('/api/gettexts', {keys: strings}).then(function(){
  // here I need to replace all keys with texts.
});
```

Is there any ellegant Angular way to do this or maybe some plugins?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/) module for that. It has a few plugins for asynchronous loading (from server for example), see here : https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading

You'll have something like  :

```
$translateProvider.useUrlLoader('api.php/translations.json');
```